# How can I make a Laravel dynamic data table?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

I want the tables to be used in a CRM project to be flexible. For example, user A should be able to increase or decrease column names. Relevant rows should be created according to the number of column names. How can I make a fully configurable and editable flextable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several approaches, out ow which I will list 2 that are applicable to SQL databases:

1. Create a sparse `meta storage`, where you will store the tuples (row, column) with their values. Drawback of this is that the table will not exists physically, and any subsequent use for query or relations will become complex
2. Use a `metadata` table that will hold the dynamic structure of the CRM table and a physical table to hold the values. Once the data in the `metadata` table is updated, you will need to change the physical storage (the table) to match the new structure. Drawback of this approach is that the changes in the physical storage can be very slow or even corrupt the data. For example, if the user decides to change a column from TEXT to INTEGER, you will loose all values in the column that can not be converted to integer.

I suggest you use some of the known ORM (object relation mapping) libraries which had solved this problem, and focus on the functionality that the end user needs.

In case of non-sql solutions, you might decide to store the table in a dynamic structure (like json), however there is limit behind how much such table can grow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will investigate what you said as this job will be quite difficult.